# Nuxt でThree.jsのnpmモジュールのexamplesフォルダをimportして使いたいがエラーが出る

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, three.js

VueとNuxtを使ったプロジェクトで3Dの描画をしたく、THREE.jsをnpmでインストールして使用したいです。THREEのメインのフォルダはimportできるのですが、examplesフォルダにある機能を読み込もうとすると以下のエラーが出ます。

**エラー内容**
SyntaxError
Unexpected token {

**コード**

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 
"three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
export default{
}
</script>
```

コードは下記公式ドキュメントからコピーしています。
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules

THREE.jsのコミュニティーにも質問したんですが、NuxtかVueの問題ではないかと言われてしまいました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/199901

Comment: 本家での質問　https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050518/how-do-i-import-three-js-into-my-nuxt-project

Comment: three.jsコミュニティでの質問　https://discourse.threejs.org/t/cannot-import-example-files-in-nuxt-js-vue-js/8463